# Unable to boot Ubuntu/Mint

Tags: boot, graphics, hybrid-graphics, modprobe, switchable-graphics

I'm posting this as a last resource

I'm really frustrated with the a new laptop I bought few months ago because I am just unable to install Linux on it. It's an HP pavilion G4 1364. Short specs: Core i3 2,2Ghz with Intel graphics (yuck), 4gb ram, 500gb HDD, Radeon HD 7390M. Not a really bad laptop, but the only distro I could install is  Fedora 18 in troubleshooting mode, which is bad because I don't like fedora/red hat/cent os, etc since I'm not really a linux power user (And I hate gnome 3 also, although I know I can switch to cinnamon or mate, but thats not really a solution for me because I have always been an ubuntu guy, since 7.04) .

I use Linux Mint at work and in my desktop, running Ubuntu on a small netbook, never had a problem installing or booting any linux distro once in my life, except for this.

- Tried Ubuntu 12.10 from a live usb, normal booting didn't work at all (it just gave me a black screen), although I could hear the Unity login sounds after a while (but still no screen). Compatibility mode didnt work, it just kept telling me about a timeout in modprobe (Video related probably) again and again. Tried nomodeset, noacpi and all the options but no luck.
- Tried Mint 14 Cinnamon from a live usb, normal booting didn't work, troubleshooting mode just kept telling me about a timeout in modprobe, like in Ubuntu.
- Tried Mint 14 MATE from a live usb, normal booting worked, troubleshooting mode just kept telling me about a timeout in modprobe, again, like in Ubuntu. But after running the live MATE live session, installing Mint, rebooting and starting grub to boot Mint, the system hangs. Maybe my video card doesn't like MDM? (Theres no MDM  on the live usb, that explains probably why MATE worked fine on the liveusb, not sure)
- Tried Fedora 18, normal booting didn't work, troubleshooting mode worked with some errors.

I'm posting this from a Linux Mint MATE live session, as Wintendo doesn't like my smartphone hotspot (ridiculous).

I bet this problem is related to the switchable-graphics (also called "hybrid graphics", depending on the vendor)  feature of my laptop. I tried with both setups in my BIOS, dynamic and static, and both have the same results. Linux detects both, but uses only Intel (by reading the Xserver log).

By the way, I checked the MD5 hash of my ISO files, and I doubt my usb key is the problem. Ubuntu was tried both, on a USB and a DVD.

Please help. I just can't not program waiting 4 seconds for a simple AJAX call to return a value (which happens in Windows running xampp).

- A dessesperate linux user.

Comment: Did you try to boot with the 'nomodeset' option? To do that, boot in the Live CD (or USB), press F6 and locate the 'nomodeset' option.

Comment: Yes, I tried all of those options.

Comment: As of Apr 15, 2013, the latest Ubuntu 13.04 test release has fixed this problem, at least for me. You don't need to boot Ubuntu in nomodeset, but I couldn't use vgaswitcheroo properly.